# Call a Stored Procedure which has errors, continue and get full output

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, output

I want to call a SQL-Server SP ([Integrity Check- Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html)) from a C# application.

In cases of any corruption found in any database (multiple) errors are thrown.

Executed within SSMS the `PRINT` output inlcudes a very informative cummulative output (log entries mixed with error messages). The execution continues after each error obviously. In SSMS you can use *output to file* to get a file with this content.

From C# I tried to use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, which works, but it breaks on the first error.

Is there any way to call a SP from C# without breaking on errors with the goal to get the full output at the end?

### EDIT:

To test this, I found a *prepared* corrupt db to download ([look here](https://www.sqlskills.com/sql-server-resources/sql-server-demos/))

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'a clean db'
    DBCC CHECKDB (someDb) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
    PRINT 'a bad db'
    DBCC CHECKDB (SomeCorruptDB) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
    PRINT 'one more clean db'
    DBCC CHECKDB (AotherGoodDB) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
END 
GO
EXEC dbo.test;
GO
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.test;
GO
```

the error messages come *from within `DBCC CHECKDB`*. The SP is executed down to the final line.

### UPDATE

Hello all helpfull people!
Thx for looking into this. Further tests brought up, that the SQL-Exception thrown within C# has got all information packed inside. I was blinded by the obvious first catch.
Diving into it, I found, that my SP was executed to the end actually. The `SqlException` has got an `.Errors` property which reflects all errors found.
Much work left to do, but problem solved.
Thx for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks on the first error"?

Comment: @DavidG, The C# application throws an error on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`, which seems to be the first error occured. The rest of the SP is not executed. I need an execution which continues down to the last line, collects all the output and let me analyse this (similiar to the output in SSMS)

Comment: Are you saying the SP continues to run after the error when you run it manually? Because I'm fairly sure that's not happening.

Comment: @DavidG See my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue on but get detailed analysis of the exception that was handled in sql you need to catch the SQL Exception.

**UPDATED**

Example error throwing procedure:

```
create proc ErrorThrower
as
RAISERROR (N'There was a problem', 15, 1);  
RAISERROR (N'There was a 2nd problem', 15, 1); 
GO
```

And a simple console app to make an ADO.NET connection and handle the failure:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var server = ".";
      var database = "tester";

      var connection = $"Server ={server};Database={database};Trusted_Connection=True;";

      var listOfErrors = new List<SqlError>();

      using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection))
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec ErrorThrower", cn))
      {
        cn.Open();

        //handles ONLY SQL Exceptions
        try
        {
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlException)
        {
          //Do what you want in your program with the failure of SQL.  I am just echoing it for example purposes, I could log it or do more with it.
          foreach(SqlError error in sqlException.Errors)
          {
             listOfErrors.Add(error);
          }

          Console.WriteLine($"There were {listOfErrors.Count} errors executing");
          listOfErrors.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"\tError was {x.Message}"));
        }

        cn.Close();
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I accepted this, because it is exactly pointing to the solution I've just found myself. Although this is not adressing the *multiple* error problem it is the solution actually (see my UPDATE section)

Comment: Well a collection of errors and such from the bubbling up of things like DBCC and other child procs may also need to be handled obviously.  See updated example for a collection handling routine.

Answer (score 2):

`PRINT` statement results and other informational/warning messages require an InfoMessage event handler:

```
static void test()
{
    try
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.InfoMessage += Connection_InfoMessage;
        var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.test", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void Connection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

You can also set `connection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true` so that errors are also returned as info messages instead being raised as exceptions. That is what SSMS does. Note that the onus is on the app code to handle true errors differently than info errors in that case since a SqlException isn't raised for those errors.

Comment: I just added an update, problem is solved... Thx for the hint to `InfoMessage`. I'll dive into this immediately :-)

Comment: @Shnugo, yea, it's probably a good idea to add the handler to log all messages returned by Ola's scripts.

Answer (score 1):

What is the error of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`?
I dont think it is the same error as "thrown" in SSMS. Most likely there is a other reason the SP breaks in C#.

As i understand it the SP just returns the error (maybe in string) when something isnt right (corruption). Thats not really throwing an error, as it just continues as you describe it.

Answer (score 0):

try to identify those parts in your SQL script and use try catch for each part, take the first part in to try catch and, collect the error information in every catch block, and after the end of the first try-catch, start next part  in another try catch block, in your SP

you can try this using following code sample

```
-- First part of your code
BEGIN TRY
  -- your first code part
  PRINT 0 / 0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- collect error information
  -- dont thro error jist collect the information to a variable
  PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH

-- start next part identified part
BEGIN TRY
  -- your first code part
  PRINT
  2
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- collect error information
  -- dont thro error jist collect the information to a variable
  PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

Comment: I know `TRY/CATCH` in `T-SQL`... The errors are **thrown from within DBCC CHECKDB**. I cannot change this unfortunately...